# iPhone X backward compatibility to cater devices below iOS 8 versions and future compatibility

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, iphone-x, ios-app-group

I am trying to make my iOS app iPhone X compatible by using Safe Area, but in this process it is only running when I check iOS 9 and above to build. This means other devices with iOS versions 8 and below wont get support.
Is there any way to make that too compatible? I am expecting  a proper and fool-proof workaround to fix this.
Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: there is no iPhone X with older version. So you don't have to worry.

Comment: please check with the updated Quest

Comment: Can anybody help me out with a solid  workaround to make iOS 8 and below versions too ,compatible keeping the safe area intact